# есть ли примеры разработки многопоточного GUI?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, gui, sfml

Делаю GUI движок для игры на SFML, и я хочу GUI запихнуть в отдельный поток, чтобы он не мешал потоку логики игры.

Есть ли паттерны для разработки GUI? MVC, MVVM рассматриваю, но это довольно древние паттерны.

Comment: Ответ: Есть. А все паттерны для GUI были придуманы давным-давно, еще во времена Win3.1 и OS/2.

Comment: @VTT Читал статью но не знаю на сколько это правда, но там было сказано что для нынешних многопоточных приложений эти паттерны не очень хорошо подходят.

Comment: Такие явления как многопоточность, асинхронность, кроссплатформенность, виртуальность и т.п. также появились давным-давно.

Comment: Наоборот, логику игры выносите в другой поток. А GUI оставьте в первоначальном.